# Horror episode or movie about a girl receiving a look-alike doll

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I vaguely remember watching either an episode or a movie during my childhood (sometime in the early 2010s I'm pretty sure) of a girl who receives a doll that looks like her. But shortly after, the doll starts doing mischievous things that the girl's mother blames the girl on. I remember specifically one scene where the doll's hand moved every so slightly to knock over a cup of milk and spill it all over the mother's laptop.

I also remember a scene where there is black ink (or blood, I can't fully remember) writing all over the wall written to by the doll, but I don't remember what it said; all I remember is that I was a very ominous scene. Then near the end, the girl starts turning into a doll while the look-alike doll turns into a human and pretends to be her. I think the girl's mother finds the girl (now transformed into a doll) in the dumpster and realizes that the doll has the girl's birthmark (or tattoo; it was some kind of identifying feature), leading her to figure out that the doll she found was her actual daughter. They somehow switch back to their original selves and the original doll is thrown away in the ditches.

This is basically all I remember... I probably have remembered many of the details wrong but hopefully this is enough detail for y'all to identify this. I remember it being very creepy when I watched it as a child and I want to re-live the experience of watching it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *The Haunting Hour*, specifically the episode *[Really You](https://rlstinesthehauntinghour.fandom.com/wiki/Really_You)*.

> Spoiled brat Lily gets her own life-sized doll and names it, "Lily D.," but when her mom starts to care for the doll more than her own daughter, strange things begin to happen.

The clip below shows the lifelike doll and an incident involving a laptop.

> 

Comment: Ah, that's exactly it! How did you find it? DId you watch it before?

Comment: @AidenChow - My Google-Fu is strong. I searched for ("TV Show" and "Doll" and "Birthmark")

Comment: What is this "Google-Fu" that you speak of??

Comment: @AidenChow - [This](https://www.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu#:~:text=Google%2Dfu%20(uncountable),useful%20information%20on%20the%20Internet.)